# How do atomic formulas with negated subjects translate into English?

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm reading about negative normal forms. My text talks about transforming *H¬x* to 'negative normal form' so it reads *¬Hx*.

If the two sentences are interchangeable, then they mean the same thing. 
So, suppose that *H* stands for *reads a lot*, and that *x* refers to someone named John.  Could one think of *¬Hx* translating in to *it is not the case that John reads a lot*, and of *H¬x* translating in to *it is the case that John does not read a lot*. (Although, I suppose they could both translate into any one English sentence that expresses their shared meaning.)

More importantly, why would anyone bother writing *H¬x*?

Comment: I've actually never seen the notation of negating a variable before. It violates the syntactic rules of most treatments of first order logic.

Comment: You can read about it here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form

Comment: @malice Of course you have seen the negation of a variable before.  Consider the law of the excluded middle: $ p \lor\lnot p $.  OP is just confused about the interpretation of $x$ here.

Comment: @MJD: In first order logic I wouldn't typically consider propositional symbols "variables" on account of them not being something you can bind with quantifiers. But I side with Quine on this issue.

Comment: Well, it's not at all clear that H here is a quantifier. In fact I'd guess it is more likely than not that it *Isn't* one and OP is confused about that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of $x$ in that expression is formally wrong - and in formal logic everything is super technical  and formal.

"Negative normal form" refers to when the not operator is fully distributed. Consider $\neg (A\wedge B)$ vs $\neg A\vee \neg B$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form) for more details.